# C++: Program for Deleting a node and return its right child:

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was attempting to solve the question for deleting a node in BST, and saw a strange output. In the case where node has only right child, I was trying to delete that node and return its right child. Somehow, both of the codes below gave the correct result, even though it seems to me like only code 1 should work since we're trying to access a deleted node.
Can someone tell me why this happens?

cpp
Code 1:

```
Node* temp = root->right;
delete root;
return temp;
```

Code 2:

```
Node* temp = root;
delete temp;
return root->right;
```

Comment: Ain't UB a wonderful thing!

Comment: *Can someone tell me why this happens?*  The programmer made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of dereferencing a deleted pointer is undefined. That means anything can happen, including having a program appear to work.

There is no promise that an exception will be thrown, or that an error message will be displayed.

The specific language in the [C++23 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/) appears in Section 6.7.5.1 [basic.stc.general], where [item 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/basic.stc.general#4) states, "Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior."